# Issue with creating insert select query in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**I have the following mySQL query that I would like to execute inside a PHP script:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO InsertingTable1 (place, device, description, amount) SELECT `place`, `device`,`description`,`amount` 
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN CheckingTable1
    ON Table1.device = CheckingTable1.device 
    ORDER BY place ASC, device ASC" ;
```

**The error I get is:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message
>   'Column 'Device' in field list is ambiguous'

Comment: This happens to be one of those errors where you can read the error message carefully and find your way to your answer.  With respect, give it a try.

Comment: try add database name to your query,like `database.InsertingTable1`

Comment: @RajithThennakoon That won't really solve the error, and the problem is with a column and not the table

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what it means by ambiguous in the field list, am I repeating the name more than I should

Comment: provide column name `device`  in `select statement` with respected `table name` like `Table1.device` or `CheckingTable1.device`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this Select statement
If you want to show the device column if the first Table named Table1.

Mysql tells you in the error message that both tabkles have such a column namede devices

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO InsertingTable1 (place, device, description, amount) SELECT `place`, Table1.`device`,`description`,`amount` 
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN CheckingTable1
    ON Table1.device = CheckingTable1.device 
    ORDER BY place ASC, device ASC" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error arises because both tables have a `device` column. As a consequence, when you `SELECT device` or `ORDER BY device`,  your RDBMS cannot assess which one it should use.

You would argue that, since you are joining on the `device` column across tables, the value of both columns is guaranteed to be the same; this is true in this specific case, but your RDMBS does not figure that by itself.

You need to prefix the column with the table it comes from. Also, it is a good practice to use table aliases, to make the query shorter. I added the prefix to the ambiguous column but I suggest that you do prefix *all* columns; this makes the query easier to understand.

```
INSERT INTO InsertingTable1 (place, device, description, amount) 
SELECT place, t.device, description, amount
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN CheckingTable1 c ON t.device = c.device 
ORDER BY place, t.device
```

NB: `ASC` is the default sorting order, hence you may not specifiy it.